# argparse: required choice between 1 argument or an argument group

Tags: python, argparse

In my python app, my users have a choice between specifying either:

- a single date
- a date range (start, end)

I have created a nested `argument_group` inside a `mutually_exclusive_group`:

```
argument_group
+--- mutually_exclusive_group
     +--- date                 (argument)
     +--- argument_group
          +--- start           (argument)
          +--- end             (argument)
```

I want to indicate to my users that **either** `date` **or** the group `(start, end)` is required, and that **if** they choose the group, both (`start, end`) are required:

This is what I have so far:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
grp = ap.add_argument_group('test dates')
date_group = grp.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

date_group.add_argument('--date', help='date (YYYYMMDD)')
date_range = date_group.add_argument_group('date range')

date_range.add_argument('--start',help='start date (YYYYMMDD)', required=True)
date_range.add_argument('--end',  help='end date (YYYYMMDD)', required=True)
```

**Problem 1:**

Specifying `(start, end)` doesn't work, as argparse is (I guess) unable to see that I've specified the `argument_group` part of the `mutually_exclusive_group` instead of `date`, and since the mutually_exclusive_group is *required*, it barfs:

```
$ ./app.py --start 20180101 --end 20180102
usage: app.py [-h] --date date --start date --end date
app.py: error: one of the arguments --date is required
```

I can work around this issue by making the mutually_exclusive_group **not required**, but this is obviously incorrect, and won't catch the case where *nothing* is specified (as it *is*, in fact, required)

**Problem 2:**

Unfortunately the help for the above does not reflect my intention:

There is no `(option_1 | option_2)` around the options in the `mutually_exclusive_group` which there would be if I didn't have a nested group.

In addition, the help for `start` and `end` isn't even shown.

```
$ ./app.py --help
usage: app.py [-h] --date date --start date --end date

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit

test dates:
  --date date        date (YYYYMMDD) (default: None)
```

What I would like is something such as:

```
$ ./app.py --help
usage: app.py [-h] (--date date | --start date --end date)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit

test dates:
  --date date        date (YYYYMMDD) (default: None)
  --start date       start date (YYYYMMDD) (default: None)
  --end date         end date (YYYYMMDD) (default: None)
```

How can I express this **required** choice between an argument and an argument group?

Comment: if `--date` is used, what is the equivalent of it in `--start` and `--end`?

Comment: @Idlehands it is as if `start` == `end`

Comment: An `argument_group` cannot be nested in in `mutually_exclusive_group`. It doesn't raise an error, but doesn't do what you want.  An `argument_group` only affects the help display; it does nothing special during parsing.  Conversely, a `mutually_exclusive` group controls the usage (within limits) and tests for occurrences during parsing (using simple xor logic, no 'and' or 'any' subgroups).

Comment: @hpaulj so in effect, what I'm looking for, argparse doesn't support?

Comment: Correct.  The builtin logic for combinations of a arguments is quite simple - just the flat xor.  I explored added a more comprehensive mechanism in a bug/issue, but I don't think it will ever be implemented.  The testing logic isn't too bad, but generating a meaningful usage line is too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment that `start == end` if `--date` is given, I'd keep things simple and stick with just the two arguments:

```
class DefaultEnd(argparse.Action):
  def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
    setattr(namespace, 'end', values)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('--start', help='date (YYYYMMDD) Mandatory', action=DefaultEnd, required=True)
ap.add_argument('--end', help='date (YYYYMMDD) Optional, defaulted to START if not provided')
```

Using the custom `argparse.Action` it also defaults `--end` to `--start` if only the latter was provided:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --start START  date (YYYYMMDD) Mandatory
  --end END      date (YYYYMMDD) Optional, defaulted to START if not provided
```

So if the params were given:

```
args = ap.parse_args(['--start','20100102', '--end', '20121123'])
# args.start = 20100102
# args.end   = 20121123
```

If not:

```
args = ap.parse_args(['--start','20100102'])

# args.start = 20100102
# args.end   = 20100102
```

You can of course, also keep things simple if you just manipulate `args` after parsing and skip the custom `argparse.Action` altogether:

```
ap.add_argument('--end', help='date (YYYYMMDD) Optional, defaulted to START if not provided', default=None)

...

args.end = args.end if args.end else args.start
```

Of course this might change how your post-args codes are being handled, so these solutions might not apply for you if your code must require `args.date`.

Comment: This is what I originally had, but then tried to make it smarter by adding the mutex group. I may go back to what you have suggested here, as it seems what I'm trying to do is currently not possible

Comment: I would stick with KISS principle if there's not considerable advantage to gain from having explicitly separate groups of `--date` and `(--start, --end)`.  It keeps your implementation cleaner.

Comment: I was going to mention KISS - it's a principle for a reason! :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you can express the choice between an argument and an argument group, but a simple solution to your problem would be to use the following:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
grp = ap.add_argument_group('test dates')
date_group = grp.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

date_group.add_argument('--date', help='date (YYYYMMDD)')
date_range = date_group.add_argument('--date-range',
    nargs=2, help='Start and End')
```

Just specify date-range as single argument with two parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever work around which I hadn't even considered! Nice one! I'd like to be more explicit about the options (as per my original question), but in lieu of that this a decent second choice